# get next and previous page titles from a URL (Razor C#)

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

I am creating a navigation component to navigate through pages and would like to get the next and previous page title from a known URL to include in the links aria-label. How do I go about doing this using Razor C#?

Comment: What do you mean by "next" and "previous" pages?  How do these relate the current url?

Comment: @hijinxbassist, what I mean is I am looking for a way to obtain the page titles of the previous and next pages from the current page to include in the navigation links' aria-label dynamically.  Doing so will provide those who use screen readers to get more content than "next" link, "previous" link.  

The solution I have is manually creating an array to hold the current, next, and previous pages values.  I am looking for a way to automate it.

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question because no one knows how the "next" and "previous" page titles can be inferred from a URL based on the information in your question.